# Remove duplicate node using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to remove duplicates from the below source XML.

**Requirement 1**
Inside `<ns0:Message1>, <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema>` will only come once, but `<sObject>` will repeat. I need to remove the cases where the combination of `<AccountId>` and `<ContactId>` has already appeared once. In this example, 3rd and 4th occurrence of `<sObject>` needs to be removed.

**Requirement 2**
Inside `<ns0:Message2>, <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>` may repeat 100's of times. No values or sub tags are expected under `<UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>`. I want to remove all duplicates and keep only the first occurrence here.

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema>
         <AccountContactRole>
            <Operation>Create</Operation>
            <ObjectType>ACRObject</ObjectType>
            <TransactionLevel>REQUIRED</TransactionLevel>
            <sObjects>
               <sObject>
                  <AccountId>A12345</AccountId>
                  <ContactId>C001</ContactId>
                  <Role>SalesPerson</Role>
               </sObject>
               <sObject>
                  <AccountId>A12345</AccountId>
                  <ContactId>C002</ContactId>
                  <Role>SalesPerson</Role>
               </sObject>
               <sObject>
                  <AccountId>A12345</AccountId>
                  <ContactId>C002</ContactId>
                  <Role>SalesPerson</Role>
               </sObject>
               <sObject>
                  <AccountId>A12345</AccountId>
                  <ContactId>C002</ContactId>
                  <Role>SalesPerson</Role>
               </sObject>
            </sObjects>
         </AccountContactRole>
      </UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema>
   </ns0:Message1>
   <ns0:Message2>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
   </ns0:Message2>
</ns0:Messages>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema>
         <AccountContactRole>
            <Operation>Create</Operation>
            <ObjectType>ACRObject</ObjectType>
            <TransactionLevel>REQUIRED</TransactionLevel>
            <sObjects>
               <sObject>
                  <AccountId>A12345</AccountId>
                  <ContactId>C001</ContactId>
                  <Role>SalesPerson</Role>
               </sObject>
               <sObject>
                  <AccountId>A12345</AccountId>
                  <ContactId>C002</ContactId>
                  <Role>SalesPerson</Role>
               </sObject>
            </sObjects>
         </AccountContactRole>
      </UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema>
   </ns0:Message1>
   <ns0:Message2>
      <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>
   </ns0:Message2>
</ns0:Messages>
```

I am new to XSL and am kind of stuck. Any help is truly appreciated.

**Here is what I tried... for the first requirement (after referring to some posts here)**

Excuse my lack of knowledge in XSL :(

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="trip-tth" match="/ns0:Messages/ns0:Message1/UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/AccountContactRole/sObjects/sObject" use="concat(AccountId, '+', ContactId)"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Messages/ns0:Message1/UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/AccountContactRole/sObjects/">   
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="sObject[generate-id(.) = generate-id( key ('trip-tth', concat(AccountId, '+', ContactId) ) )]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sObjects">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have written any XSLT code, please share it. Which version of XSLT are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0? The solution is different based on the XSLT version.

Comment: Added the code I tried... This is what I came up after referring to some examples.

Comment: I am looking for a solution using XSLT v1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can optimize the key declaration by specifying only the element name in the `match` instead of entire XPath.

```
<xsl:key name="group-key" match="sObject" use="concat(AccountId, '|', ContactId)" />
```

We use the `identity template` to copy the nodes and attributes from the input XML as is to output and then start overriding the templates as per the requirement.

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Match the `<sObject>` using the key declared.

```
<xsl:template match="sObject[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-key', concat(AccountId, '|', ContactId))[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Remove the remaining `<sObject>` elements by a "do nothing" template.

```
<xsl:template match="sObject" />
```

For the 2nd requirement, you can retain the 1st `<UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema/>` and remove the rest by using the following templates.

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:Message2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema[1]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns0:Message2/UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema" />
```

The entire XSLT is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="group-key" match="sObject" use="concat(AccountId, '|', ContactId)" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sObject[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-key', concat(AccountId, '|', ContactId))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sObject" />

    <xsl:template match="ns0:Message2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema[1]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns0:Message2/UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
        <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema>
            <AccountContactRole>
                <Operation>Create</Operation>
                <ObjectType>ACRObject</ObjectType>
                <TransactionLevel>REQUIRED</TransactionLevel>
                <sObjects>
                    <sObject>
                        <AccountId>A12345</AccountId>
                        <ContactId>C001</ContactId>
                        <Role>SalesPerson</Role>
                    </sObject>
                    <sObject>
                        <AccountId>A12345</AccountId>
                        <ContactId>C002</ContactId>
                        <Role>SalesPerson</Role>
                    </sObject>
                </sObjects>
            </AccountContactRole>
        </UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema>
    </ns0:Message1>
    <ns0:Message2>
        <UpdateMultipleObjectsOperationsSchema />
    </ns0:Message2>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket. It works perfectly. Thanks for the step by step explanation. It helped a lot!